# HTML5 canvas: Same code outputs different results in different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, opera

In a simple canvas test I created for performance and quality measurement purposes, a `canvas` is painted with randomised colors and images during an unlimited period.

A sample is shown here: http://litterific.com/minisite/

> **Warning**: Only open this in Opera or Chrome, the script is pretty heavy can hang up on slow computers, don't leave the script running while you are getting coffee ;)) It is just a rough prototype and did not optimize it.

What I noticed here is that the results as painted by the script (`js/asset.js`) are different in various browsers. Especially in Opera there is much more *"green"* in the painting than in Chrome

[image]

code is found here: http://litterific.com/minisite/js/asset.js

My question is:

**How this is caused. Different random seeds? Different rounding or different color behavior in Opera?**

Note: It is exactly the same script in both browsers, so perhaps you could have a look at it in both Chrome and Opera.

Comment: The first thing I'd would try is to use an alternative random number generator for which you can provide a seed, or just use the same pre-generated array of numbers, so that both browsers get the same input.

Comment: I tried this in Firefox 3.6. The performance isn't *too* bad - it stutters a bit (I'm guessing garbage collection), but there is results, and it's quite reddish, with a bit of black, like Chrome. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1722364/Screenshot-3.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not random numbers causing the problems, it's "funny" pixel data. Here's the change:

```
for (i = 0, n = pixels.data.length; i < n; i += 4){
  pixels.data[i + 0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, Math.floor(r * f)));
  pixels.data[i + 1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, Math.floor(g * f)));
  pixels.data[i + 2] = 0;
  pixels.data[i + 3] = pixels.data[i + 3]; 
}
```

If you ensure that the pixel values are integers in the right range, Opera works fine.

Oh also, and this is probably obvious, it goes a lot faster if you hoist those multiplications out of the loop.

Comment: I suspected something like this. that means that all values above 255 in pixels.data[0] are put in pixels.data[1] (and multiplied by 255) ? so { pixels.data[0] = 300 } would be the same as { pixels.data[0] = 255, pixels.data[1] = 45 } ? That makes sense since Javascript does not know numeric types between 0 and 255 but only "integers". (in opera's case that makes the array pretty useless, since in opera only the first pixeldata needs to be filled, bit like colors in C# or PHP.) but is somewhat "fixed" in Chrome. I also dumped this question at Opera, perhaps it's  some sort of unfinished issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens; you may be correct that the value "spills" into other color cells, but it's hard to say exactly. (I suppose you could figure it out by experimentation.)

Comment: yeah, you're right, going to look after that. thanks for your efforts anyway, much appreciated. Tested it a bit and, you confirmed my suspicion. Bounty will apply in 17 hours from now ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed, Math.random starts with a different seed in each case.  There is unfortunately no way to provide a fixed seed to the Math.random function. If you really need that, you will have to find one or implement it yourself.

I have noticed that different canvas implementations do vary slightly when drawing partially opaque objects, but that is a minor issue compared to your differing random sequences!

Btw, your script does produce nice looking output :)

Comment: I've tested with plain numbers... still producing the output different, also in a loop.